# Regex for Maven artifact-like paths

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I'm trying to come up with a regex for the following case...

We're doing a cleanup of some Maven artifacts which were incorrectly deployed to a repository. The Maven format for naming artifacts is like this:

```
${groupId}/${artifactId}/${version}/${artifactId}-${version}-${classifier}.jar
```

Where:

- `groupId` : The ID of the group (common package name) for the artifact, for example `com.foo` (the dots get expanded to wildcards by Maven)
- `artifactId` : The ID of the artifact, for example `bar`
- `version` : The version, for example `1.2.3`
- `classifier` : This is an optional property which allows you to specify a sub-artifact, for example `sources`, `javadocs`, `jdk14`, etc... This may, or may not exist.

Here are some valid paths:

```
com/foo/bar/1.2.3/bar-1.2.3.jar
com/foo/bar/1.2.3/bar-1.2.3.pom
com/foo/blah/1.2.3/blah-1.2.3.jar
com/foo/blah/1.2.3/blah-1.2.3.pom
com/foo/blah/1.2.3/blah-1.2.3-javadocs.jar
com/foo/blah/1.2.3/blah-1.2.3-sources.jar
com/foo/blah/1.2.3-SNAPSHOT/blah-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
com/foo/blah/1.2.3-SNAPSHOT/blah-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT.pom
com/foo/blah/1.2.3-SNAPSHOT/blah-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT-javadocs.jar
com/foo/blah/1.2.3-SNAPSHOT/blah-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
com/foo/myapp/user-management/1.2.3/user-management-1.2.3.jar
com/foo/myapp/user-management/1.2.3/user-management-1.2.3.pom
```

I need to find any matching invalid paths using `grep` (as I have the massive list of files in the repository) for the following:

```
com/foo/bar/1.2.3/blah.jar        {notice how:
                                   a) the artifactId is not part of the file name;
                                   b) there is no specified version

                                   In this case com/foo would be the groupId,
                                   but blah is not the artifactId
                                   and there is no version
                                  }
blah/1.zip                        {notice how there is no:
                                   a) artifactId
                                   b) version component of the path
                                  }
```

The above illustrates cases which don't follow the Maven format explained in the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you try to match file names with the `grep`. But here is the `find` command to find all non-matching files:

```
find . -type f ! -regex '.*/\([^/]*\)/\([^/]*\)/\1-\2[^/]*'
```

I match only for the `artifactId` and `version`, since you haven't specified precisely anything else (and apparently not even mandated the `.jar` extension (the `blah/1.zip` doesn't list `.zip` as an error)).

To delete the offending files, simply add the `-delete` to the `find` invocation:

```
find . -type f ! -regex '.*/\([^/]*\)/\([^/]*\)/\1-\2[^/]*' -delete
```

---

Edit1: The same regex for `grep`:

```
egrep -v '^.*/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/\1-\2[^/]*$'
```

Comment: I already have a narrowed list of files I gathered with `find`... It's a heavy search, so I'd prefer to `grep` the file

Comment: @carlspring, then use the ClasG's answer. The principle stays the same: using the `\1`/`\2`/`\3` to enforce the file name convention. There is no other way to do it with the regular expressions.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, your regex seems to be working for the wrong set of paths. I'm actually interested in the ones from the second list which has explanations. I have tried your regex against it and it doesn't seem to match.

Comment: @carlspring, yes, it doesn't match the second list (the list of exception) which as I have understood you want to identify. The match (the regex) is positive, thus it matches the first list, but it is then negated on the `find` command line with the `!`. Thus listing everything that does NOT match the regex (akin to `grep -v`).

Comment: @carlspring Since ClasG mixed up regex flavors (which I have missed previously too) I have added a grep variant too. Note that unlike ClasG, I do not match the file extension.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
^(?![\w\/]*\/(\w+)\/([\w-]+)\/([\d.]+)\/\2-\3(-\w+)?\.(\w+)).*$
```

It'll capture the different parts in separate groups and verify that required parts are there.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mP9lA2/4).

**Edit:**

Missed the fact that you're interested in the ones *not* matching. Changed regex and example.

Comment: Thanks! Could it be made to accept any extension (they're not always just `.jar`, or `.pom`, I just gave these for the sake of the example, sorry...)?

Comment: Sure - just change the `(jar|pom)` to `(\w+)`.

Comment: Changed answer to suit your needs ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: @ClasG, you used the PCRE - the `grep` doesn't support PCRE. I have tried it with `perl` instead - `perl -nE 'print if /<regex>/'` - it also didn't work: it printed everything.